# Как закрыть Python 3.7.1 Shell?

Tags: python, shell

Как закрыть Python 3.7.1 Shell после того как скрипт успешно отработал?
Или может знаете как очистить окно? Программа ежедневно запускается из-за чего в Shell скапливается много информации.

Comment: Вот так закрыть: `quit()`

Comment: Можешь добавить скрипт того как запускаешь? И как из скрипта выходишь?

Comment: После quit(), появляется сообщение `do you want kill it?`

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть здесь, объясняется довольно подробно: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747371/python-exit-commands-why-so-many-and-when-should-each-be-used